# How do i navigate through folders in code behind?

Tags: vb.net, navigation, directory

I need to address a file in my code. this file isn't located in my main project, but in a library project. When i call AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, i end up in the start project's (let's call it mainproject) debug folder. What i want to to is call appdomain.cd.bd and go up 3 levels, so i leave debug, then bin and then mainproject. Then i would navigate to libraryproject and to folder where file is located.

What i've tried so far is do AD.CD.BD\..\.. or AD.CD.BD/../..
I thought i remembered those, but it's a no go.

Does anyone know how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is concerning to see you wanting to codify paths based on project build paths. What happens when you release the project and these project directories don't exist.

I would recommend that if there is a file your project needs to execute is from a library project that doesn't get copied across during the build that you use a post build step to copy this file to the same location as your assembly. Alternatively you may be able to set the build action on the file in your project which might get this file to your main project build output directory.

Answer (score 0):

Three levels up would be `../../../` wouldn't it?

Comment: how would you apply that to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory?

Comment: Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"..\..\..\OtherProject\bin\Debug");

Comment: @btlog, this is generating an "expression expected" error at the"@" sign

Comment: Sorry, my bad, that is only for c#. Just remove the @ symbol for vb.